# Extract left text outside the parenthesis if any

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to extract the text on the left, outside the parenthesis ():

```
import re
clean_title = re.match(r'(.*)\(.*\)', title.lower()) 
if clean_title:
   return clean_title.group(1).rstrip()
```

Any suggestions to improve it, maybe without regex?

Expected results:

```
>>'Alone in the Dark (The Cincinnati Series Book 2)'
>>'alone in the dark'
```

Comment: How certain are you that the parentheses will either occur in a pair at the end of the title, or not at all? Is there any chance of nested parentheses? How should it behave in such unexpected situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)  to split the whole text based on the first occurrence of the `(` character. This will return a list, pick the first element of the list:

```
>>> text = 'Alone in the Dark (The Cincinnati Series Book 2)'
>>> text.split('(')[0]
'Alone in the Dark '
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the text on the left cannot contain opening parenthesis, **splitting by the first opening parenthesis** might work as well:

```
>>> clean_title = 'Alone in the Dark (The Cincinnati Series Book 2)'
>>> clean_title.split('(', 1)[0].lower().rstrip()
'alone in the dark'
```

Note that it will not fail even if there are no parenthesis:

```
>>> clean_title = 'Test'
>>> clean_title.split('(', 1)[0].lower().rstrip()
'test'
```

---

As far as the regular expression approach, you might also use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) which would not require checking if there is a match or not. And, as a bonus, let's account for the extra space before the parenthesis:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(.*?)\s?\(.*?\)", r"\1", clean_title).lower()
'alone in the dark'
```

Or:

```
>>> re.sub(r"\s?\(.*?\)", r"", clean_title).lower()
'alone in the dark'
```

You can also do the lowering part in a replacement function:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(.*?)\s?\(.*?\)", lambda m: m.group(1).lower(), clean_title)
'alone in the dark'
```

Also note that I'm using [non-greedy regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Comment: `r"(.*?)\s?\(.*?\)", r"\1"` seems overkill if not using the lambda - `r"\s*\(.*\)", ""` (replacing with nothing) should be enough, right?

Comment: @muru good point, included into the answer, thanks!